# Composer with same title but different Piece

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

There are two tables to be used in this question they are

```
    Piece(PNo, CNo, Title, Tune, Opus).
    Composer(CNo, Last, First, Born, Died)
```

I have to List the composer’s first and last names, the titles of these music pieces along with the number of times the composer did that with the music piece title.

I am using Microsoft access

I have tried

```
     SELECT PIECE.TITLE,COMPOSER.FIRST, COMPOSER.LAST, COUNT(*) 
     FROM PIECE, COMPOSER
     GROUP BY PIECE.TITLE 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Help with this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I had select, group, etc. but I did not type the code in properly when i was posting the question. I apologize for the confusion, I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `join` condition between the tables:

```
 SELECT PIECE.TITLE, COMPOSER.FIRST, COMPOSER.LAST, COUNT(*) 
 FROM PIECE INNER JOIN
      COMPOSER
      PIECE.CNO = COMPOSER.CNO
 GROUP BY PIECE.TITLE, COMPOSER.FIRST, COMPOSER.LAST
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

Comment: @user3363156 . . . Access requires the "INNER" in `INNER JOIN`.